# What does "<>" mean?

Tags: operators

Looking over code examples in my lecture slides, I notice this:

```
c = head();
s = null;

while (c <> null && s == null) {
  if (c.value().matches("33812"))
    s = c

  c = next
}
```

Whilst I understand basically what the code does, I don't understand this particular part of the while loop condition "c <> null".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's almost certainly just a typo/braino for `!=` ("not equal to"). `<>` is used in Basic and SQL, but not in any C-like language I'm familiar with.

Comment: `<>` can also be used in Perl, but it means something else entirely (IANA Perl coder, so I can't say exactly what, and it's hard to google for).

Comment: In Perl it means 'read a line from the list of files provided as arguments to the perl file, or

Answer (score 2):

`c <> null` is the same as `c != null`, which means that `c` is not equal to `null`. I can't think of any languages offhand that use it, but I know they exist. (Haskell uses `<>`, but it's for something *completely* different, and uses `/=` for null because it looks like the symbol ≠.)

Comment: Pascal/Delphi. I often type '<>' in C/C++ code.  The compiler is not impressed.

Comment: "which means that c is not equal to null" - Pedantry, but I don't like the wording of that. It doesn't *mean* that c is not equal to null, it *tests* if c is not equal to null.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, <> means != or not equal to. The reasoning behind this is one operand cannot be equal if it is strictly greater/less than the other operand, thus <> really means all numeric possibilities EXCEPT ==, that is, !=.

Answer (score 0):

`<>` and `!=` mean "not equal to".  SQL uses `<>` in general; depending on the language, this is either equivalent to `!=` or not supported by its lexer.